# Is switching the number of processes used efficient

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am fairly new to threaded programming. I wrote a small script to download photos in parallel. If I loop through a list of objects each with an amount of photos ranging from 0 to 20+ is it more efficient to have a static amount of threads in the thread pool or varying, based on number of images? Some initial tests suggest having a static amount makes sense, ran some stats on data, geometric mean was about 15.5 images and average was 23.

```
def processObj(obj):
  # this is function called per object
  from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
  from functools import partial
  # .... processing object that may have multiple photos
  # numPhotos is the num of photos to download
  if len(allPhotos) < 10:
      numProcess = 6
    else:
      numProcess = 12
    getLogger('info').info('\t Extracting Photos')
    pool = Pool(numProcess)
  # processPhoto downloads photo
  download_func = partial(processPhoto, folderName = folderName)
  # photoList is a list of urls to photos
  results = pool.map(download_func, photoList)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

Comment: Run some benchmarks, it'll tell you more than a bunch of strangers on the internet.

Comment: You might want to use async instead of multiprocessing/threading. Here is a good article on it: https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Imports should go at the top of the file.

Comment: Ya. I was looking for different kind of comments.